# Wrong Documentation beta score in Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, area-51, documentation-beta

In [Area 51 Stack Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com), in [one of my commitments](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/88145/humor), I see my total reputation is suddenly increased.

Hover on the each community in the score board, I see the Documentation beta reputation is 4,662 (the same reputation as Stack Overflow), actually I scored only 175 in the documentation beta.

So the Stack Overflow reputations and badges are duplicating in the Area 51 score card.

As I know the [Data migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281373/312043) from Documentation beta to Stack Overflow is in-progress. But this is looking like a bug to me.

Screenshot for reference.

[image: Area 51 wrong Documentation beta score]

Comment: It results in duplicating your SO profil (rep and badges)

Comment: Reported in meta [SO] as well: [In Area 51, Reputation and badges of Documentation are the same as Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328407/1983854).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things came together to make this possible.

Area 51 periodically pulls a list of sites through the API and updates its own internal records. So it happily created a record in its Sites table for docs-beta, even though there was no actual site proposal to go along with it.

I didn't realize that happened, so didn't flip the State that record to indicate that the site was no longer in private beta. (That part apparently doesn't get updated via the API. It just checks for new sites, IIRC, not doing a diff on what's going on state-wise.)

But on top of that, Area 51 also maintains a list of site associations for each user in JSON format, including site's id, the user's id on that site, and the user's reputation. This is where this gets fun: because of the site record created above, A51 dutifully made requests to the docs-beta site asking for users' reputation... and we just as dutifully redirected those requests to Stack Overflow. So basically everyone with an SO profile ended up with an effectively duplicate association record, regardless of whether they even joined the docs-beta site or not.

Fun stuff.

Site record has been updated in Area 51 and associations regenerated, so everything should be back to normal now.

Comment: Admit it, it was fun! (Well, surely some diversion from your day-to-day tasks... ;-))

Answer (score 5):

This is most probably caused by the redirection of Docs-beta to Stack Overflow.

When Area 51 retrieves the reputation for Docs-beta, it gets redirected to Stack Overflow, resulting in both Docs-beta and Stack Overflow having the same reputation.

But technically, Docs-beta shouldn't be showing up in the first place.

(*This's just my guess, but most probably the cause of this.*)

Comment: That's about the best guess I have, too. I can't think of what exactly would make that redirect behave this way, but there's probably some dumb assumption somewhere. I'll dig, but there are other more high-priority issues at the moment.

Comment: @Adam 6 weeks later, had any chance to dig? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not in any meaningful way. See above: higher priority stuff is on tap.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I found a few minutes today. See my answer. :)